# Apache RewriteRule: preserve Query String and Add new parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm not sure whether this is the origin of the bug I'm trying to solve, however, I'm still not sure I correctly understood Apache doc...

Let's say I wanna redirect

```
toto.page?a=2&c=546EUE&stuff=blah
```

to

```
index.page?view=Blahblah/Toto&a=2&c=546EUE&stuff=blah
```

Of course, if there was other parameters, they should be preserved too.

Is the following rule correct?

```
RewriteRule ^toto\.page$    index.page?view=Blahblah/Toto     [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Does this rule not work or why do you ask whether the rule is correct?

Comment: does this rule work for what I wanna do (which preserve any params appended to the match string) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is correct.